# Need to find the component with marking 500

Tags: components, identification

I am having hard time in finding what this component is . It has 8 pins and a marking on it says `500`.  It has 2 pins on bottom on each side and two on each top side.

On the board 2 pins on left bottom are as inputs and two on the right are used as outputs.

I searched for it on SMD codeBook as well as [this site](http://chip.tomsk.ru/chip/chipdoc.nsf?OpenDatabase) but couldn't find anything.

I hope some one can help here. It is part of a rs485 circuitry on a board. There is another Sot23 marked `W216j` I couldn't find this also. This is how they are connected. **Please ignore the pin names on SOT23/IC1**

[image]

[image]
[image]

---

**UPDTAE""

---

I have got the product and its the exact one by help provided by @Tom and @jp314
[This is the product that was marked 500](http://www.newark.com/wurth-elektronik/744242510/filter-common-mode-choke-80v-400ma/dp/08P2555?ost=744242510&selectedCategoryId=&categoryName=All%20Categories&categoryNameResp=All%20Categories), The SOT package is quite lear but still I couldn't get the exact one.

Comment: The SMD codebooks I know of only contain info about components that happen to have a datasheet in English. There's however a fairly vast swath of components that have datasheets only in Chinese these days... if they are public at all. Sometimes it's easier to figure out what such a component does from the circuit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to post this as an answer as I've seen the same type of question come up multiple times, and for each I've basically commented the same thing:

---

It's pretty much impossible to identify this sort of component unless you either have a BOM of the circuit, schematic, or already know what they are.

If you have some rough idea of the function they perform and it is something more complex than say a discreet transistor, then you *may* be able to identify them by searching for parts with that functionality on manufacturer websites and comparing marking codes from datasheets. But really this is a shot in the dark.

---

Having said that, based on your description, the SOT23 package device is almost certainly some sort of TVS device - used for ESD and Transient (EFT) protection on inputs. These are quite common on RS485 devices as per [this TI application note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla292a/slla292a.pdf). There are components like this specifically for RS485 in the same package like [this one](http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/sm712.pdf). Doesn't have the same marking code, but will like have the same function.

The other package as pointed out by @jp314 in the comments is likely some kind of line filter. As you have found [WE](http://katalog.we-online.de/de/pbs/WE-SLM) has some in a similar package with similar markings, so this is quite clearly what it is. In fact looking at the datasheets from that link, [this part](http://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/744242510.pdf) has a marking of `500` and looks identical to your picture.

For both of these parts, it could be inferred from the circuit what the parts do. Finding a datasheet for the exact part is the hard bit.

Comment: Is it a common-mode filter ?

Can you measure the resistance between the 2 top pins (one one each side) ? Between the two lower ones ? If it appears low (< 10 ohm), then it's probably a choke (inductor).

Comment: @jp314 the resistance is somewhat 1 Ohm

Comment: @jp314 http://katalog.we-online.de/de/pbs/WE-SLM

Comment: @dmSherazi something like that, yeah.

Comment: @dmSherazi in fact the datasheet is likely [this](http://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/744242510.pdf) - says in it that the marking is ```500```.

Comment: @jp314 Thanks for your help, from your guidance I was able to find the product page. I am still confused why it has these 4 pins on top side ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 windings on the toroidal transformer. The top connections are 1 coil, the bottom are the other. For signals that pass through differentially, the windings 'cancel'; for common-mode signals, the windings 'add' and tend to limit the currents.